# Failed to start tomcat.service: Unit tomcat.service not found

Tags: java, services, tomcat

I cannot seem to run a tomcat service from regular user and while I try this as root i get

```
root@ip-:/home/ubuntu# service tomcat
Run as /etc/init.d/tomcat <start|stop|restart>
root@ip-:/home/ubuntu# service tomcat start
Failed to start tomcat.service: Unit tomcat.service not found.
root@ip-:/home/ubuntu#
```

I did run it manually and it seemed to work

```
root@ip-:/home/ubuntu# /etc/init.d/tomcat start
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat/current_tomcat
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat/current_tomcat
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/current_tomcat/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/local/java/current_java
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/current_tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/current_tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar

Tomcat started.
```

If i run it as a regular user I cannot seem to get permission. I have users under no pass word only ssh keys.

```
ubuntu@ip-:~$ service tomcat start
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-units ===
Authentication is required to start 'tomcat.service'.
Multiple identities can be used for authentication:
 1.  Ubuntu (ubuntu)
 2.  An,,, (an)
Choose identity to authenticate as (1-2): 1
Password: 
polkit-agent-helper-1: pam_authenticate failed: Authentication failure
==== AUTHENTICATION FAILED ===
Failed to start tomcat.service: Access denied
See system logs and 'systemctl status tomcat.service' for details.
ubuntu@ip-:~$
```

And here is the script for service

```
ubuntu@ip-:~# cat /etc/init.d/tomcat 
#!/bin/bash
export CATALINA_HOME=/usr/local/tomcat/current_tomcat`
start() {
 sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
}
stop() {
 sh $CATALINA_HOME/bin/shutdown.sh
}
case $1 in
  start|stop) $1;;
  restart) stop; start;;
  *) echo "Run as $0 <start|stop|restart>"; exit 1;;
esac
ubuntu@ip-:~# ll /etc/init.d/tomcat 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 306 Feb 14 07:20 /etc/init.d/tomcat*
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 while encountering this problem. I have solved it.

Firstly, add one line to the top of the script:

```
. /lib/lsb/init-functions
```

Then in shell, create symbolic links from /etc/rc* to my script:

```
sudo update-rc.d tomcat defaults 95
```

This will also make your script be running automatically after rebooting.

Comment: worked for me, although I didn't had to add that first line, and also dropped the 95 (but seems that leaving it is the same)